# css class scss çevirme extent

Tags: css, sass

I want to extend the classes that I defined with scss,but anyway he gets it all, e.g. 1 .vue-button .vue-x .vue-y .vue-z I want it covered.then 2. vue-buttononly .vue-x
I want it covered. as css I wanted to write what I did as scss but it doesn't work the way I want

Summarize what he seeks to do,

How can I write the `CSS` example written below as SCSS?

css example

```
.vue-button, .vue-x, .vue-y, .vue-z{
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.vue-button, .vue-x{
   padding: 0 20px !important;
   border-radius: 9999px !important;
}
```

scss

```
.vue-button {
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.vue-x {
   @extend .vue-button
}
.vue-y {
   @extend .vue-button
}
.vue-z {
   @extend .vue-button
}

.vue-button {
   padding: 0 20px !important;
   border-radius: 9999px !important;
}

.vue-x {
   @extend .vue-button
}

``
```

Answer (score 0):

In such case you should use `mixins` instead of extending the class.

Add scss like this:

```
@mixin common-css {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.vue-button,
.vue-x,
.vue-y,
.vue-z {
  @include common-css;
}

.vue-button,
.vue-x {
  padding: 0 20px !important;
  border-radius: 9999px !important;
}
```

Then you should get your desired result as:

```
.vue-button, .vue-x, .vue-y, .vue-z{
   display: inline-block;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
.vue-button, .vue-x{
   padding: 0 20px !important;
   border-radius: 9999px !important;
}
```

Comment: this is not scss

Comment: Can you please clarify a little more what exactly do you want?
From your question I can understand that you want to write scss which will generate the css code result as given in `css` section of your question after css file generation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to convert what I wrote in css to scss

Comment: @Liza Are you sure you want to convert css to scss? AFAIK we need to convert scss into css, not vice-versa. There is no use of converting css into scss. Please confirm once.
You can check online tools if you directly want to convert css into scss.

Comment: @Liza Yes, the code that I have written in `scss` section gives exact output as your code written in `css` section. You can try it online: https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243994/discussion-between-akshay-and-liza).